# Proving of disproving a claim regarding limits

Tags: calculus, limits, supremum-and-infimum

I need to prove or disprove the following claim:
if $$\lim_{x\to x_0}  f(x)=L$$ and the set $$A=\lbrace f(x): x\in \Bbb R \rbrace$$ is bounded from above, then $$sup(A)\geq L$$
I tried proving by assuming towards contradiction that $L>sup(A)$ and use the epsilon property of $sup(A)$ but was not able to move on from there.
I also tried to disprove the claim with some split functions such that will have $L>f(x)$ for every $f(x) \in A$ but could not find a way to prove the limit.
Assistance will be welcomed.

Comment: "I tried proving by assuming towards contradiction that $L>$sup$(A)$ and use the epsilon property of sup$(A)$ but was not able to move on from there." : Don't understand the significance of the phrase "the epsilon property of sup$(A)$".  Informally, there is a contradiction inherent in the assumption that $L > $sup$(A)$.  Take $\epsilon < L - \text{sup}(A)$.  Per the definition of a limit, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that in a neighborhood of radius $\delta$ around $x_0$, there is at least one value of $x$ (in fact the entire neighborhood) such that $f(x) > \text{sup}(A)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aiming for a contradiction, suppose that $S=\sup(A)<L$. Let $$\varepsilon=\frac{L-S}{2}>0$$
On the one hand, $$f(x)\leq S\quad\text{for all }x\in\mathbb{R}$$
On the other hand, the interval
$$(L-\varepsilon,L+\varepsilon) $$ must contain values of $f$ because of the given limit. Can you see the contradiction between the two? (Hint: compare the numbers $L-\varepsilon$ and $S$.)